# Why does Vulkan use CPU blitting on Windows 10 in windowed mode? (presentmon)

Tags: windows, winapi, graphics, vulkan

When running the cube.exe sample from the LunarG Vulkan SDK, presentmon reports that it uses CPU blitting (in contrast to GPU blitting, the default for D3D11, or even flipping).

Considering that this could mean that the entire surface has to be sent from  the GPU back to host memory, copied somewhere, and then sent back to the GPU, this seems actually pretty undesirable.

Is this

- Fixable at all (except by Microsoft)?
- A bug in presentmon?
- A bug in the Vulkan API implementation?
- A bug in the sample application implementation?

And does it actually have a performance or latency impact?

Comment: BTW OpenGL according to it seems to use the same thing.